# Any efficient way to update very large matrix?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I have a very large matrix, which is a 2D array with few hundred rows but around 2 million columns. My application needs to update this matrix row by rows with one painful constraint. To update a specific row, it needs to wait all columns of previous rows updated. And the process is very slow.

For example:

```
matrix = [[0 for x in xrange(2000000)] for y in xrange(300)]
for i in xrange(1, 300):
    for j in xrange(2000000):
        k = a random column in row i-1
        matrix[i][j] = matrix[i-1][k] * simple_function(i) # some calculation
```

- To update `matrix[i][j]` , I need to have the value of row `i-1`

My initial thought is to use multi-process approach to parallelize `j` loop in each `i` round. However, the calculation in `j` loop is too light. The process creation cost is much higher than calculation (I also tried process pool).

Second thought is to use thread, it works well with almost no performance gain due to GIL limitation.

I would like to know if there's any other approach that can accelerate the my code. Thank you.

BTW, I know Cython can work without GIL. But the calculation function needs to access a Python object and it will takes lots of works to modify the original code.

Comment: If the result of `simple_function` only depends on `i` you could store the result once in the outer loop and reuse it in the inner one. And what is `k`?

Comment: If `k` is a typo for `j` then it seems like you swap the order of iteration of `i` and `j` and then parallelize the outermost loop on `j`, giving each parallel job a chunk of columns to be processed in row order. As @schwobaseggl points out, you could also pre-compute simple_function and use it in all the workers, assuming no pesky side effects.

Comment: Thank you both. I've updated my question. `K` is a random column in row `i-1`. And simple_function also need to access columns in `i-1` row.

Comment: Any particular reason not to use python 3? Did you have a look at [Scipy/Numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/)?

Comment: I don't think Python3 or numpy/scipy is able to solve this issue. If they can, I'd love to know how to.

Answer (score 0):

**Use Numba for such tasks**

https://numba.pydata.org/
If you wan't a matrix or an array create one (and not a List of Lists). I would also recommend to take a look at some beginners tutorials regarding numpy.

Example code:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb
import time

def main():
    matrix = np.random.rand(2000000,300)
    t1=time.time()
    k=100
    Testing(matrix,100)
    print(time.time()-t1)

@nb.jit(cache=True)
def Testing(matrix,k):
    for i in xrange(1, matrix.shape[0]):
        #inline your simple function (in my case np.power(i,2))
        res_of_func=np.power(i,2)
        for j in xrange(matrix.shape[1]):
            matrix[i,j] = matrix[i-1,k] * res_of_func

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The matrix calculation takes 0.5 seconds on my machine (Haswell i7).
On Python 2 parallelizing with numba on windows isn't working today. But the jit compiled code should be aproximately 100 times faster.